# Will HIVE do a full table query with both partition conditions and not partition conditions?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, explain, hive-partitions

I have a hive table partitioned by one date column name `datetime`

If I do a query like

```
select *
from table
where datetime = "2021-05-01"
    and id in (1,2)
```

with extra `and id in (1,2)` condition, will hive do a full table search?

Is it possible to determine it by `explain`result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partition pruning should work fine. To verify use `EXPLAIN DEPENDENCY` command, it will print input partitions in JSON array `{"input_partitions":[...]}`

See [EXPLAIN DEPENDENCY docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Explain#LanguageManualExplain-TheDEPENDENCYClause).

[EXPLAIN EXTENDED also prints used partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50859735/2700344).