# Querying based on Partition and non-partition column in Hive

Tags: hive, parquet, hadoop-partitioning, hive-partitions

I have an external Hive table as follows :-

```
CREATE external TABLE sales (
ItemNbr STRING,
itemShippedQty INT,
itemDeptNbr SMALLINT,
gateOutUserId STRING,
code VARCHAR(3),
trackingId STRING,
baseDivCode STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (countryCode STRING, sourceNbr INT, date STRING)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/user/sales/';
```

where table is partitioned by 3 columns ( countryCode, sourceNbr , date). I know that if i query based on these 3 partition columns, my query would be faster.

I have some queries on other query pattern :-

1. If i add non-partitioned column along with partitioned column like countryCode, sourceNbr , date , **ItemNbr** as part of where condition when executing sql query , will it scan the full table or it will scan only inside the folder based on countryCode, sourceNbr , date  and look for itemNbr attribute value specified in where condition?
2. Giving all columns is necessary to filter the record or
   sub-filter also works like if i give only first 2 columns
   (countryCode, sourceNbr ) as part of where condition. In this case
   it would scan the full table or it would search only inside folders
   based on 2 columns condition (countryCode, sourceNbr ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partition pruning works in all your cases, no matter all partition columns are in WHERE or only partial, other filters do not affect partition pruning.

To check it use `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` command, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50859735/2700344